# displaying sound in Python GUI

Tags: python, qt, pyqtgraph

I have a class that connects to the microphone of the laptop and plots the frequency of the sound in real-time in a new window but I want to display the result in a GUI that I prepared.

can you help me to integrate these two codes?

the code to read the microphone. it should be saved as soundcardlib.py:

```
#################
## DO NOT EDIT ##
#################

from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import pyaudio


def data_to_array(data, channels):
    return (np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.int16)
            .reshape((-1, channels))
            .astype(float) / 2**15)


class SoundCardDataSource(object):
    def __init__(self, num_chunks, channels=1, sampling_rate=44100, chunk_size=1024):
        self.fs = sampling_rate
        self.channels = int(channels)
        self.chunk_size = int(chunk_size)
        self.num_chunks = int(num_chunks)

        # Check format is supported
        self.pyaudio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream = None
        dev = self.pyaudio.get_default_input_device_info()
        if not self.pyaudio.is_format_supported(
                rate=sampling_rate,
                input_device=dev['index'],
                input_channels=channels,
                input_format=pyaudio.paInt16):
            raise RuntimeError("Unsupported audio format or rate")

        # Allocate buffers
        self._allocate_buffer()

        # Callback function is called with new audio data
        def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
            samples = data_to_array(in_data, self.channels)
            self._write_chunk(samples)
            return (None, pyaudio.paContinue)

        # Start the stream
        self.stream = self.pyaudio.open(
            format=pyaudio.paInt16,
            channels=self.channels,
            frames_per_buffer=self.chunk_size,
            rate=self.fs,
            stream_callback=callback,
            input=True
        )

    def __del__(self):
        if self.stream:
            self.stream.stop_stream()
            self.stream.close()
        self.pyaudio.terminate()

    def _write_chunk(self, samples):
        self.buffer[self.next_chunk, :, :] = samples
        self.next_chunk = (self.next_chunk + 1) % self.buffer.shape[0]

    def _allocate_buffer(self):
        self.buffer = np.zeros((self._num_chunks,
                                self.chunk_size,
                                self.channels))
        self.next_chunk = 0

    @property
    def num_chunks(self):
        return self._num_chunks

    @num_chunks.setter
    def num_chunks(self, num_chunks):
        n = max(1, int(num_chunks))
        if n * self.chunk_size > 2**16:
            n = 2**16 // self.chunk_size
        self._num_chunks = n
        self._allocate_buffer()

    def get_buffer(self):
        """Return all chunks joined together"""
        a = self.buffer[:self.next_chunk]
        b = self.buffer[self.next_chunk:]
        return np.concatenate((b, a), axis=0) \
                 .reshape((self.buffer.shape[0] * self.buffer.shape[1],
                           self.buffer.shape[2]))

    @property
    def timeValues(self):
        N = self.buffer.shape[0] * self.buffer.shape[1]
        return np.linspace(0, N/self.fs, N)
```

the code to plot the sound and its frequency domain. it should be saved in RealTimeFFT_main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import division

import numpy as np
# from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore  # for OLD libraries/python versions
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets  # for NEW versions
import pyqtgraph as pg
from soundcardlib import SoundCardDataSource


# Based on a function from numpy 1.8, not all versions have it so we have to define it in case
def rfftfreq(n, d=1.0):
    if not isinstance(n, int):
        raise ValueError("n should be an integer")
    val = 1.0 / (n * d)
    N = n // 2 + 1
    results = np.arange(0, N, dtype=int)
    return results * val


def fft_buffer(x):
    window = np.hanning(x.shape[0])
    # Calculate FFT
    fx = np.fft.rfft(window * x)
    # Convert to normalised PSD
    Pxx = abs(fx) ** 2 / (np.abs(window) ** 2).sum()
    # Scale for one-sided
    Pxx[1:-1] *= 2
    return Pxx ** 0.5


# class RealTimeFFTWindow(pg.GraphicsWindow):  # for OLD libraries/python versions
class RealTimeFFTWindow(pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget):  # for NEW versions
    def __init__(self, soundcardlib):
        super(RealTimeFFTWindow, self).__init__(title="")
        self.soundcardlib = soundcardlib
        self.paused = False
        self.downsample = True

        # Setup first plot (time domain)
        self.p1 = self.addPlot()
        self.p1.setLabel('bottom', 'Time', 's')
        self.p1.setLabel('left', 'Amplitude')
        self.p1.setTitle("")
        self.p1.setLimits(xMin=0, yMin=-1, yMax=1)
        self.ts = self.p1.plot(pen='y')

        self.nextRow()

        # Setup second plot (frequency domain)
        self.p2 = self.addPlot()
        self.p2.setLabel('bottom', 'Frequency', 'Hz')
        self.p2.setLimits(xMin=0, yMin=0)
        self.spec = self.p2.plot(pen=(50, 100, 200), brush=(50, 100, 200), fillLevel=-100)

        # Data ranges
        self.reset_ranges()
        # Timer to update plots
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
        interval_ms = 1000 * (self.soundcardlib.chunk_size / self.soundcardlib.fs)
        self.timer.start(int(interval_ms))
        # Show plots
        self.show()  # for NEW versions, comes with pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget

    def reset_ranges(self):
        self.timeValues = self.soundcardlib.timeValues
        self.freqValues = rfftfreq(len(self.timeValues), 1. / self.soundcardlib.fs)

        self.p1.setRange(xRange=(0, self.timeValues[-1]), yRange=(-1, 1))
        self.p1.setLimits(xMin=0, xMax=self.timeValues[-1], yMin=-1, yMax=1)

        self.p2.setRange(xRange=(0, self.freqValues[-1] / 2), yRange=(0, 50))
        self.p2.setLimits(xMax=self.freqValues[-1], yMax=50)
        self.spec.setData(fillLevel=0)
        self.p2.setLabel('left', 'PSD', '1 / Hz')

    def update(self):
        if self.paused:
            return
        data = self.soundcardlib.get_buffer()
        weighting = np.exp(self.timeValues / self.timeValues[-1])
        Pxx = fft_buffer(weighting * data[:, 0])

        if self.downsample:
            downsample_args = dict(autoDownsample=False, downsampleMethod='subsample', downsample=10)
        else:
            downsample_args = dict(autoDownsample=True)

        self.ts.setData(x=self.timeValues, y=data[:, 0], **downsample_args)
        self.spec.setData(x=self.freqValues, y=(20 * np.log10(Pxx)))

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        text = event.text()
        # Use spacebar to pause the graph
        if text == " ":
            self.paused = not self.paused
            self.p1.setTitle("PAUSED" if self.paused else "")
        else:
            super(RealTimeFFTWindow, self).keyPressEvent(event)


# app = QtGui.QApplication([])  # for OLD libraries/python versions
# app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])  # for NEW versions

# # Setup soundcardlib
# FS = 44000  # Hz
# soundcardlib = SoundCardDataSource(num_chunks=3, sampling_rate=FS, chunk_size=4 * 1024)
# win = RealTimeFFTWindow(soundcardlib)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

the GUI which must be saved as gui_easy.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1071</width>
    <height>837</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
    <item>
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QWidget" name="mplwindow" native="true">
        <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
         <item>
          <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
           <item>
            <widget class="PlotWidget" name="graphWidget" native="true"/>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>300</width>
          <height>0</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>200</width>
          <height>16777215</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="title">
         <string>Options</string>
        </property>
        <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_4">
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="start_btn">
           <property name="text">
            <string>Start</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_4">
           <property name="title">
            <string>Parameters</string>
           </property>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
            <item>
             <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_2">
              <property name="title">
               <string>Name</string>
              </property>
              <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_7">
               <item>
                <widget class="QLabel" name="label_7">
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>Max Freq</string>
                 </property>
                </widget>
               </item>
              </layout>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_3">
              <property name="title">
               <string>Value</string>
              </property>
              <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_8">
               <item>
                <widget class="QLineEdit" name="max_freq">
                 <property name="text">
                  <string>0</string>
                 </property>
                </widget>
               </item>
              </layout>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
            <size>
             <width>20</width>
             <height>40</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </spacer>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1071</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>PlotWidget</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>pyqtgraph.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

and finally my code for the GUI:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys  # We need sys so that we can pass argv to QApplication
import os


from soundcardlib import SoundCardDataSource
from RealTimeFFT_main import RealTimeFFTWindow


FS = 44000  # Hz
soundcardlib = SoundCardDataSource(num_chunks=3, sampling_rate=FS, chunk_size=4 * 1024)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphWidget)
        
        #Load the UI Page
        uic.loadUi('gui_easy.ui', self)
        
        self.start_btn.clicked.connect(self.display_sound) 

    def display_sound(self):
        print("done")

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: I want to show my plots in this window]